# Create variable number of buttons for an html form

Tags: javascript, html, button, freemarker

I'm trying to make some changes to a questionnaire. Currently on each page there is an html form which has 3 submit buttons with values "next", "back", and "home". The value of the button gets passed through to the java controlling everything so that it knows which page to load next.

What I want to do is have a button along the bottom for each page in the questionnaire - however, this number varies between questionnaires.

The total number of pages is passed through as $(totalNumber) by some freemarker code. I'm new to programming, so instinctively I want to write some kind of "for" loop in javascript that will create a new button each loop and increment a dummy variable to get the right number of buttons, but I can't work out how to do this (and I'm not sure if this is the right way of going about this!)

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Can you provide some example code of your form and how you've tried to solve the problem so far? I'm sure that will help us come up with a solution more quickly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you `totalPages` is at least 1:

```
<#list 1..totalPages as pageNumber>
   <input type="button" value="${pageNumber}" onclick="goToPage(${pageNumber})" />
</#list>
```

The HTML (using `input button`, `onclick`, etc.) is not part of the advice... I just show how to use FreeMarker.

Answer (score 0):

I had a very similar question of my own that the other answer did not help me. I was just learning web development, so I did not know how to dynamically create buttons or other elements. You are able to dynamically create elements in a JavaScript function like this:

```
function add() {
    var element = document.createElement("input");
    element.setAttribute("name", "whatever");
    var elementAbove = document.getElementById("elementAbove");
    elementAbove.appendChild(element);
}
```

You can make a for loop inside there to dynamically add however many elements you would like.